# Unbounded linear operator on Hilbert spaces that is everywhere defined

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

I know a lot of examples of linear operator $T$ on $H$ such that $D(T) \subsetneq H$ and $T$ is not bounded, and such kind of operators are very important in analysis of PDEs.

However, I don't know any example of linear operator $T$ on $H$ such that $D(T)=H$
and $T$ is not bounded. Does anyone knows?

Comment: Sorry if it is a silly question, but... what is $D(T)$?

Comment: Note that, in some ways, unbounded operators are naturally not defined everywhere. Indeed, if $T$ is defined everywhere and *closed*, then the closed graph theorem implies that $T$ is bounded. One of our primary interest in the study of unbounded operators is the theory of *closeable* unbounded operators and by the above, these are *necessarily* not defined everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. $D(T)$ is domain of $T$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou You can find unbouned operators defined on the whole space as in my answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sure. They just won't be closed.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thank you for your comment. Your comment has deepened my understanding of the closed graph theorem and unbounded operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$ or any linearly independent sequence of unit vectors. Extend this sequence to  a (Hamel) basis $(e_n) \cup (x_i)_{i \in I}$. Define$T(e_n)=ne_n$ and $T(x_i)=0$ for all $i$. This extends to an unbounded linear map from $H$ into $H$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your answer is wrong, because $T$ is not defined. For example, if $x := \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/n)e_n \in H$, then $Tx$ is not defined.

Comment: Any map defined on basis elements extends uniquely to a linear map on the whole space. Your $x$ has another expression as  **finite** linear combination of $e_n$'s and $x_i$'s and that expression is used to define $Tx$. @heppoko_taroh

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wrong and now I got it.